# Best way to get Tokens in java

Tags: java, parsing

I have files with some naming conventions -

```
Ex 1 - filename1.en.html.xslt
Ex 2 - filename2.de.text.xslt

where en/de - language, html/text - output 

I need to read individual files and populate the java object accordingly.

Also, en should be converted to en-US etc, while populating the language field.

Format.java

private String language ;
private string output ;
```

What is the best way to do this? I know it can be done through plain indexOf or using string tokenizer or parsing thru regex.

If regex is better any code samples please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [StringTokenizer](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=236), but [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) should mostly do the trick.

```
String foo = "filename1.en.html.xslt"
String[] parts = foo.split("\\."); // regex: need to escape dot
System.out.println(parts[1]); // outputs "en"
```

With StringTokenizer you could do:

```
String foo = "filename1.en.html.xslt"
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(foo, ".");
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    String part = tokenizer.nextToken();
    parts.add(part);
}

System.out.println(parts.get(1)); // "en"
```

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter how you parse the filename as long as it works for you. If you want to take the regex route, a [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) like this will work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.xslt");
```

The first capture group is the filename, the second is the language, and the third is the output.

---

That said, a regex does seem like overkill, so what's wrong with using `String#split()`?